# Regex to match string in code files

Tags: c#, regex

I have thousands of code files in my solution and I am trying to find all 'Resource.X' references in those files.

For instance, part of one of the code files is

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-9">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnAddEnvironmentRole">@Resources.ES_Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelAddEnvironmentRole">@Resources.ES_Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

I need to match

"Resources.ES_Save" AND "Resources.ES_Cancel"

There's thousands of code files and thousands of Resources.X varieties, but they all begin with "Resources."

I'm close with

\bResources..*[a-z]\b

but that's matching the first Resources.Save to nearly the end of the file.

Comment: check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear..., this is just ONE example.  I am searching thousands of files (cs, cshtml, etc.) in a solution for thousands of unique "Resource.?" words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason, I agree with @mybirthname that HTML Agility Pack is the way to go instead of regexes when trying to extract HTML, but in this case we're just looking for a snippet of razor code, so a regex makes sense to me. Assuming you really want to just find "Resources.ES_Save" AND "Resources.ES_Cancel", this should be adequate:

```
(?<Resource>@Resources\.ES_(?:Save|Cancel))
```

The named capture will also make it easier to access. If you need to match all resources you could do this:

```
(?<Resource>@Resources\.\w+)
```

Comment: Your second option was very close to what i needed.  Thanks a ton!   \bResources.\w+\b

Comment: Jason, I didn't add the word boundary because I thought you were matching the Razor @ with it as well, I would still match with the @ and just strip it. This way you are guaranteed it's a resource from code, but the likelihood of text aside from the code looking like Resources.ES_Save is probably pretty low. Also, I updated the answer because I forgot to escape the period.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find all instances across my entire solution.  Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Regex for HTML. They are a lot of discussion about that you can read it. Instead of that you should use HTML Parser. You can do it with HTML Agility Pack.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);//html is string


        var coll = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "button" && x.Attribute["id"] != null && (x.Attribute["id"].Value == "btnAddEnvironmentRole" || x.Attribute["id"].Value == "btnCancelAddEnvironmentRole")).ToList();

        foreach(HtmlNode node in coll)
        {
             string text = node.InnerText // this will return the text in the node
        }
```

You can google [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), the dll is in NuGet too.